# How to plot trips durations while considering their deadlines?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My input is a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'blk1': {'a': '12h45', 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 'blk2': {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': '13h15', 'd': '15h15'},
 'blk3': {'a': None, 'b': '12h10', 'c': None, 'd': None},
 'blk4': {'a': None, 'b': '15h45', 'c': '13h30', 'd': None},
 'blk5': {'a': '13h30', 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': '16h15'},
 'deadline': {'a': '13h00', 'b': '14h30', 'c': '15h00', 'd': '15h45'}})
```

```
   blk1   blk2   blk3   blk4   blk5  deadline
a  12h45                       13h30    13h00
b                12h10  15h45           14h30
c         13h15         13h30           15h00
d         15h15                16h15    15h45
```

And I'm trying to get the plot below. Basically, I need to compute the duration an element (a, b, c or d) took to go from one block to another. By the way, only two non null values are possible per each row and the direction of a trip is from left columns to right ones.

[image]

I feel like I'm in the right way but can't figure out how to make the colored (red or green) dashed lines and also how to add the texts (block x to y):

```
df1 = df.drop(columns='deadline').sort_index(ascending=False)
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Hh%M'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df2.min(axis=1),df2.max(axis=1)]).T
df2.columns = ['start', 'end']
df2['duration'] = (df2['end'] - df2['start'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
df2 = df2.reset_index()
ax.barh(data=df2, width='duration', y='index', left='start', ec='k', color='k,' height=0.2)
ax.set_xlim(df2['start'].min(), df2['end'].max())
```

[image]

Comment: Do you always have 3 points per row?

Comment: Yes, there is always two values in [blk1, ... blk5] and one value in the deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reshape and plot each line:

```
tmp = (pd.to_datetime(df.stack(), format='%Hh%M')
         .rename_axis(['group', 'type'])
         .reset_index(name='time')
         .sort_values(by=['group', 'time'])       
      )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))

for i, (k, g) in enumerate(tmp.groupby('group', sort=False)):
    ax.plot(g['time'].iloc[:2], [i]*2, color='k', lw=5)
    ax.plot(g['time'].iloc[1:], [i]*2, lw=5, ls=':',
            color='r' if g['type'].iloc[1] == 'deadline' else 'g')

ax.invert_yaxis()
labels = tmp['group'].unique()
ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
```

Output:

[image]

`tmp`:

```
   group      type                time
0      a      blk1 1900-01-01 12:45:00
2      a  deadline 1900-01-01 13:00:00
1      a      blk5 1900-01-01 13:30:00
3      b      blk3 1900-01-01 12:10:00
5      b  deadline 1900-01-01 14:30:00
4      b      blk4 1900-01-01 15:45:00
6      c      blk2 1900-01-01 13:15:00
7      c      blk4 1900-01-01 13:30:00
8      c  deadline 1900-01-01 15:00:00
9      d      blk2 1900-01-01 15:15:00
11     d  deadline 1900-01-01 15:45:00
10     d      blk5 1900-01-01 16:15:00
```

With markers:

adding `marker='|', markersize=20, solid_capstyle='butt'` and `ax.set_ylim(-0.5, len(labels)-0.5)`:

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! I will take over and go make the final adjustments. Thank you.

Comment: One small question: do you by any chance know how to make the lines like this ┣━━┫ ?

Comment: @VERBOSE sure, add `marker='|', markersize=20, solid_capstyle='butt'`. For more flexibility you can also use arrows instead of lines.